# Create graph in silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, graph

Please help me. I want to create a graph to visualize the flow of funds by using Silverlight 3 and databases.

Answer (score 0):

in Silverlight Toolkit [Silverlight at codeplex](http://silverlight.codeplex.com) you have charts and other usefull stuff. But I think it's Silverlight 4 only. If you can, please upgrade to Silverlight 4.

Samples [Silverlight Toolkit Samples](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html)

Comment: Some of my friends suggested me to use graphlight, but I do not understand how to use graphlight in Silverlight. I am still very new in Silverlight. Can you tell me step by step using graphlight in Silverlight applications. thank you very much